# How to split dataframe equally by different values of a column in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, linechart

I have a data frame df and I want to split/subset it by specific values in a column.
The column that contains those values is the column ID. The reason for that is because I want to generate line charts for every each different ID. My real dataset has a lot of unique IDs so if I generate line charts for every ID in the same page it will be difficult to read them. So I am thinking to split the dataset into smaller datasets that will contain lets say 5 different IDs. Is there anyone that can help or can think of a better idea?

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
"F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", "F3", 
"F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", 
"F4", "F4", "F4"), Date = c("22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", 
"25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "22/6/2021", 
"23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", "25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", 
"28/6/2021", "29/6/2021", "22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", 
"25/6/2021", "26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "29/6/2021", 
"30/6/2021", "22/6/2021", "23/6/2021", "24/6/2021", "25/6/2021", 
"26/6/2021", "27/6/2021", "28/6/2021", "29/6/2021"), Values = c(9.6, 
9.8, 10.2, 9.8, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 
1.4, 1.1, 3266, 3256, 7044, 6868, 6556, 3405, 3410, 3980, 5567, 
59.4, 56, 52.8, 52.4, 55.5, 54, 61, 53.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

These are the lines of code for the line charts. The problem is that there are a lot of different IDs and when I run this code all the line charts are on the same page and it's difficult to read them. Also, the date cannot be shown since everything is squeezed. I could put all the lines in only one chart but the range of the values for every ID is different.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(Date), y = Values)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = ID)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free')
```

Comment: Do you need `split(df, df$ID)`

Comment: the function is correct but  I am looking at how to put a parameter so it will split is by 5 different IDs. I tried this `dflarge <- df[which(df$ID == "F1" ),] 
dfOther <- df[!(1:dim(df)[1]) %in% c(which(df$ID == "F1"))] but i cannot put more than one different IDs in this which function @akrun

Comment: The `split` should return a list based on the unique values in 'ID'

Comment: i understand but i want smaller datasets with several IDs. For example. if I have 20 IDs i want to create 4 datasets with 5 IDs @akrun

Comment: Can you check the solution posted.  Is that you wanted

Comment: sorry i was out. It does what I asked. But can you tell me why we have to save it as a pdf? and why this lines of code are not producing the plots in Rstudio? `out <- map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
           ggplot(aes(x = factor(Date), y = Values)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = ID)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free')) `

Comment: It is because we are storing that output as an object and not `print`ing it.. You can just call `out` and it shows or wrap the whole with `print` i.e. `print(.x %>% ....`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235715/discussion-between-pipts-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `%/%` to do the `split` on a sequence index created with `match`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(purrr)
lst1 <- df %>% 
             group_split(grp =((match(ID, unique(ID)) -1) %/% 5 + 1))
```

Now, loop over the list with `map` and create the plots and save as `.pdf`

```
out <- map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
           ggplot(aes(x = factor(Date), y = Values)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = ID)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free'))
ggsave(
   filename = "plots.pdf", 
   plot = marrangeGrob(out, nrow=1, ncol=1), 
   width = 15, height = 9
)
```